# Edit link on php table

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a table where values are from the database. I need to incorporate the edit link to the table. Wherein if the user clicks "edit", the value from the database will be put in a textbox where the user can edit it, then save to the database. It's working on my first row of value but not on the succeeding rows. PLease help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".loginDetails").click(function(e) {
    var input = $("<input>", {
      val: $(this).text(),
      type: "text"
    });
    $(this).replaceWith(input);
  });

  $("#edit-record").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("span.loginDetails").trigger("click");
  });
});
```

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM details"; 
$queryres = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 

while ($rowwaf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryres)) { 
echo "<form action=\ "update.php\" method=\ "POST\">\n"; 
echo "<td><span class=\ "loginDetails\"> ".$rowwaf["name"]." </span><a href=\ "#\" id=\ "edit-record\"> Edit </a></td>\n" ; 
echo "<td>".$rowwaf["address"]."</td>\n" ; 
echo "</form>\n" ; 
}
```

Comment: your html markup is invalid. You cannot legitimately straddle table cell elements with a form element ~ the form must either wholly contain the entire table or the form should be wholly contained in a single table cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you could do the `edit` button call via class instead of id .Because `id` is unique for the entire document.That why its working on first row element.
2. while on edit click target the span via parent `td` like `$(this).closest('td').`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".loginDetails").click(function(e) {
    var input = $("<input>", {
      val: $(this).text(),
      type: "text"
    });
    $(this).replaceWith(input);
  });

  $(".edit-record").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('td').find("span.loginDetails").trigger("click");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing a mistake here you are using the id in the edit hyper link you have to change this into the class.
like this:

```
$(".edit-record").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('td').find("span.loginDetails").trigger("click");  });
```

in you while loop change id into class into the hyper link in this way like :

```
echo "<td><span class=\ "loginDetails\"> ".$rowwaf["name"]." </span><a href=\ "#\" class=\ "edit-record\"> Edit </a></td>\n" ;
```